# How to find out objects created by hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using hibernate3 and spring 3 in a project.

Number of domain objects are quite a lot and some relations between objects are eager. I am trying to fine tune the application. I created the eager-fetch diagram between objects, however, now I need to find out which objects are being created by hibernate.

Is there a way to find out domain objects being created by hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be to start looking out for the SQL queries that are getting generated for your most hit pages or pages that are taking more time to load.

Enable features, `Show SQL`, for the same.

Also `OneToOne`, `ManyToOne` are Eager by default, make them lazy.

Also with `OneToOne`, there is some issue, [refer here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/one-to-one-and-lazy-vs-eager-loading.html)

Making use of first level, second level and query cache.

Creating `indexes`.

Also try with `net.bull.javamelody.MonitoredWithSpring`

Java Melody Changes

Add the below dependency in `pom file`

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
             <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
             <version>1.50.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Add the below in `web.xml` file

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>displayed-counters</param-name>
            <param-value>spring,http,sql,error,log </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>disabled</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-config/mvc/monitoring-spring.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

**`monitoring-spring.xml`**

```
<bean id="monitoringAdvisor" class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringAdvisor">
    <property name="pointcut">
        <bean class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoredWithAnnotationPointcut"/>
    </property>
</bean>

Use annotations in controller or services like below
 @MonitoredWithSpring(name = "XYZ")
```

Append the url `/monitoring` to your context path. Then you can see the graph.

Comment: javamelody looks pretty awesome do you have any idea about it? not many on stackoverflow though...

Comment: @hevi i think you can post another question for the same, but accept answer for your problem here

Comment: admins make a lot of fuss about posting general questions even if they are upvoted. such a pitty.